# Excel VBA protected, but can't see to run

Tags: vba, excel

I have several macros that I want to share with my company. Unfortunately to protect my code from others messing with it, I lock the macro, but it doesn't allow end users to see the macros on their end. I can get it onto their computer just fine and see it if I pull up the VBA editor. Unable to run it without unlocking the project or running from a seperate project.

Is there a workaround to lock the project but allow them to run the macros?

Comment: VBE password protection shouldn't have this effect. Did you make them private?

Comment: No, everything is set to public, there are only 2 modules and 3 seperate subs, but it doesn't allow anyone else to see the macros to run from the toolbar.

Comment: And they're not stored in `personal` workbook? If not, not sure what's going on :/

Comment: It isn't in a personal workbook, they are stored in a seperate vba project

Comment: This is a stupid way to do it but you could build a userform that let's user select the "macro" they want to run.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in a past company. Sometimes companies enforce the "disable all macros without verification" setting found in Trust Center -> Macro Settings -> Macro Settings.

Alternately, some policies prevent running of unsigned modules. You can sign your project from the Visual Basic Editor Window (that's the alt-F11 window) and clicking Tools -> Digital Signature.

Another possibility is that you have set up IRM on your workbook and the users involved don't have the correct permissions.

I'm interested in your solution.

Comment: I have checked all of these things and no luck getting access to the subs outside of unlocking the code.

Comment: Bummer. Is there a lock screen message? What exactly does excel tell you when trying to run code from your subs?

Comment: Also, could you just make a button or keyboard shortcut for the macros you need to run? This could be a usable workaround until you figure the issue out. Another idea, you've locked the VBA module, and if the workbook is also protected, sometimes I've had strange issues with macros.

Comment: Well we are just sharing the code itself. There isn't a workbook associated with it, we use the macro on a bunch of different workbooks, with a lot of variety. But for some reason, no one can see the macro to add it to their toolbar. Seeing it in the VB editor is fine, and once it is unlocked, it shows up to put it on the toolbar.